# Access SQL Conditional Clause Multiple Conditions/Records Same Column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've run into a problem trying to write some SQL for MS Access that will parse some of the data down in the way I was hoping. While I'm admittedly new (or still learning beyond the bounds of a college class I took five years ago) with regards to SQL, I'd like to think what I'm trying to do can be accomplished.

The scenario:
While I might not have started this all of that efficient to start with, I began with two tables. The original dataset started with a little under 72k records.

The goal, or what I was seeking to accomplish in the case was to find all of the records where someone appeared for more than one Charge, and the outcome for a charge that is defined as having 0 points is guilty, however the other charges are found either NG or Dismissed.

Here is what I have so far. That data I started with came from two tables, one which contained the appearances, one that had the codes and points.

An example for the appearances would be similar to the following:

```
APP    DATE      CHARGE    OUTCOME  
===================================
1      1/1/2014   137      GT        
2      1/5/2014   122      GT        
2      1/5/2014   123      DI       
3      1/6/2014   257      DI
3      1/6/2014   257      DI
4      1/6/2014   137      NG
4      1/6/2014   123      DI
4      1/6/2014   122      GT
```

I had a second table which linked the charge, to the potential number of points associated with the charge, fairly simple formatting there

```
CHARGE    POINT
===============
122       0
123       2
137       2
257       0
```

So I created a few basic queries, since I'm largely filling in the blanks based on a bulk data file that was provided to me. The first one pulled joined the first two tables together, so I was left with a table that looked something along the lines of:

```
APP    DATE      CHARGE    OUTCOME  POINTS
==========================================
1      1/1/2014   137      GT       2      
2      1/5/2014   122      GT       0
2      1/5/2014   123      DI       2
3      1/6/2014   257      DI       0
3      1/6/2014   257      DI       0
4      1/6/2014   137      NG       2
4      1/6/2014   123      DI       2
4      1/6/2014   122      GT       0
```

I then created three small queries that were each asked to produce a subset of data from the main query, one for OUTCOME=GT, Points=0, another for Outcome=NG, Points>2, the last Outcome=DI, Points>2. Each one of the queries was called in a make table query that brought the record set down from the original 72k to 39k. Applying yet another query with

```
Select * from record_set Where RecordID IN
(Select RecordID from record_Set
GROUP BY RecordID
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1))
```

on the end brought the total down to just under 21k.

My problem is this:
The dataset I would like to return needs to further filter the results. Currently I haven't figured out how to weed out the APP values where both values are 0. For all I know I should have approached this a completely different way.

EDIT:
What I would be looking for is the dataset that returns to look something like this:

```
APP    DATE      CHARGE    OUTCOME  POINTS
==========================================      
2      1/5/2014   122      GT       0
2      1/5/2014   123      DI       2
4      1/6/2014   137      NG       2
4      1/6/2014   123      DI       2
4      1/6/2014   122      GT       0
```

Where the single record was pulled, and the APP where the OUTCOME was DI/0 for all the Charges involved.

The current attempts I have tried using a straight forward WHERE clause only evaluate the records single value. I guess I'm looking for a way to evaluate both. Maybe that would be easier if I wrote the value to separate temp tables and then did a union only for the APP values that appeared in both tables?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MS-Access experience is rather close to zero, but I believe this syntax will work.  At least it might spark some ideas.

```
SELECT APP, DATE, CHARGE, OUTCOME, POINTS
FROM APP A
INNER JOIN CHARGE C on C.Charge = A.Charge
WHERE (Outcome = 'GT' and Points = '0')
OR (Outcome = 'NG' and Points > '2')
OR (Outcome = 'DI' and Points > '2')
```

I'm not sure what you mean by cases when both values are 0, but more than likely you can add another `WHERE` clause to filter those out as well.

EDIT:

> I guess the data set I am seeking will always have the following: More
>   than one APP, while containing one record with 0 PTS that was a GT,
>   and one (or more records) that can be a point value greater than 0
>   that is either DI or NG. The reason I started at 2 is that I know
>   there aren't any values that contain a 1, but I guess to be thorough
>   they could be included

First get APPs that meet the 0 PT and GT requirements:

```
SELECT APP
FROM APP A
INNER JOIN CHARGE C on C.Charge = A.Charge
WHERE Outcome = 'GT'
AND Points = '0'
```

Reuse above to get APPs that have point values greater than 0 and DI or NG:

```
SELECT APP
FROM APP A
INNER JOIN CHARGE C on C.Charge = A.Charge
WHERE (Outcome = 'DI' AND Points > '0')
OR (Outcome = 'NG' AND Points > '0')
```

Next, combine the above logic into one query, using two subqueries, in order to only pull APP data that meets both requirements:

```
SELECT APP, DATE, A.CHARGE, OUTCOME, POINTS
FROM APP A
INNER JOIN CHARGE C on C.Charge = A.Charge
WHERE APP IN (
   SELECT APP
   FROM APP A
   INNER JOIN CHARGE C on C.Charge = A.Charge
   WHERE Outcome = 'GT'
   AND Points = '0'
)
AND APP IN (
   SELECT APP
   FROM APP A
   INNER JOIN CHARGE C on C.Charge = A.Charge
   WHERE (Outcome = 'NG' AND Points > '0')
   OR (Outcome = 'DI' AND Points > '0')
)
```

This will result in only APPs that have a GT, 0 PT charge, AND another charge that is DI or NG with 1 or greater PTs.

Comment: Sorry about that, I cleaned up my question to be a little clearer. What I am trying to do is weed out all the instances where say a record contained point values that were only 0. So if someone had 5 records, I need to be able to compare them against themselves.

Comment: The only thought I had to solve this so far was as follows: separate the charges/app combinations that have points from those that don't. Generate a list of just the applicable APP and then compare it between the two tables. If one doesn't appear in both, then it wouldn't be included....maybe? thoughts?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - testing my suggestion with your logic will leave you with the result set you requested.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97c0c/3

Comment: Note: I made points greater than or equal to 2, instead of greater than 2.  I think that's what you meant to write, otherwise it will only return GT/0.

Comment: In this case, with the larger data set it leaves me with records that only have one entry; which isn't part of what I'm looking for. It's the correlation between two records from the APP that is the part that's tripping me up. When I applied the logic you suggested it did indeed cut down the record set a great deal (kudos to that by the way, I hadn't thought of filtering some of the data out ahead of time like that).

Comment: I guess the data set I am seeking will always have the following: More than one APP, while containing one record with 0 PTS that was a GT, and one (or more records) that can be a point value greater than 0 that is either DI or NG.  The reason I started at 2 is that I know there aren't any values that contain a 1, but I guess to be thorough they could be included.

Comment: That looks like it's got it when applied to the data set I have. It clears out all the instances I was getting in the first attempts.  Thank you for taking the time to work through the answer on this!